# Repeatable Multi-Colum Data Rows in Wordpress Custom Post Type

Tags: mysql, wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I'm moving a sports website from .asp to wordpress.

I have two custom post types:

1. Players
2. Tournaments

I need to be able to enter scores into the tournaments for players from the player post type.

The scoring tablulation is as follows:

**Player ID First Name  Last Name   City    State   Points  Place   Scores**

And I need to be able to add more rows, selecting the players to add the above info for.

The current ASP tables look like this, for each tournament:

[image]

And I need to be able to add unlimited rows (repeater).

It would be easy if it was just one column, I could use something like Advanced Custom Fields repeater field, but I do not know how to add rows of related multi-column data, which I can then query and display on the front-end.

Also, I would make each scoring row it's own post, but it would be waaay too many posts.

What I want, is for each tournament (stored in the tournaments CPT), to be able to add the scoring rows there, selecting the player from the player post type, and filling out the columns, as seen, with the ability to add as many rows as there are players for each tournament.

Thank you for your help follow programmers! I've been doing this a fairly long time, but this is a new use-case for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Meta Box Group](https://metabox.io/plugins/meta-box-group/) plugin. It allows you to create repeatable group of fields.

So, in your situation, you need to create a group of player (`post` field), first name, last name, city, state, points, place, score. Then make the whole group repeatable. (In Meta Box, it uses another term **clone**).

Comment: Wow. Thank you Sir. I can't say enough how grateful I am. Bless you!